# Get the property of an object on click of a button in dynamic content

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, dynamic, key-value

I'm completely new to angularjs.
I've created some dynamic content using an array containing objects.
Now, my dynamic content has a button which will call upon a method to get the corresponding ID of the object from the 'myData' array.

I'm confused on how do I write this method to get the corresponding object's id from the myData array.

Could you please help me with that?

Here's the code

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [{
    company: "ABC",
    url: "www.abc.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "1"
  }, {
    company: "CDE",
    url: "www.cde.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "2"
  }, {
    company: "DEF",
    url: "www.def.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "3"
  }];


  $scope.getID = function() {
    console.log(this);

  };

});
```

```css
.event {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in myData" class="event">
    Company: <span>{{obj.company}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  Type: <span>{{obj.type}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  URL: <span>{{obj.url}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="getID()">Get ID</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could pass whole object to `ng-click` method parameter like `getID(obj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button ng-click="getID(obj.id)">Get ID</button> // pass id from template to controller



  $scope.getID = function(id) {
     $scope.forEach(function(obj){ // loop through your data
         if(obj.id === id) { // if passed id equals to object id
            console.log(obj) // get desired object
         }
     })

  };
```

Or you can do it like

```
<button ng-click="getID(obj.id, myData)">Get ID</button>

  $scope.getID = function(id, myData) {
     myData.forEach(function(obj){
         if(obj.id === id) {
            console.log(obj) // desired object
         }
     })

  };
```

Comment: How could I miss such a simple thing! Anyways, thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

just pass the obj.id as function parameter :

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = [{
    company: "ABC",
    url: "www.abc.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "1"
  }, {
    company: "CDE",
    url: "www.cde.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "2"
  }, {
    company: "DEF",
    url: "www.def.com",
    type: "company",
    id: "3"
  }];


  $scope.getID = function(id) {
    console.log(id);

  };

});
```

```css
.event {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in myData" class="event">
    Company: <span>{{obj.company}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  Type: <span>{{obj.type}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  URL: <span>{{obj.url}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="getID(obj.id)">Get ID</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton :) I will have to select the previous answer as the best one, since it gives me the option to get hold of the entire object :)